# Proguard obfuscation keywords for kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I was using this **keywords** for **obfuscation** with **proguard** in my **android-java** project :

```
do
if
for
int
new
try
byte
case
char
else
goto
long
this
void
break
catch
class
const
final
float
short
super
throw
while
double
import
native
public
return
static
switch
throws
boolean
default
extends
finally
package
private
abstract
continue
strictfp
volatile
interface
protected
transient
implements
instanceof
synchronized
```

but I'm switching to **Kotlin** and now the question is what keywords should i use for Kotlin ?

I've found [this](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html) but should i use all of them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what proguard obfuscates. Proguard operates on Java Bytecode. Giving it a list of keywords from a JVM language really doesn't do anything for your obfuscation.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you please tell me what should i use for my obfuscation dictionary ?

Comment: Just use the defaults provided by android: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-code - If you don't fully understand what proguard does you should not attempt to edit those defaults.